# Dual boot backtrack 5 with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, backtrack

Is there a way to do it without a boot disc (something like wubi)?
Even if not, is there a way to do it so that the bootloader stays the same (i.e. remains the bootloader for win7 as opposed to grub)?

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Backtrack first, then install Windows 7, the Windows bootloader will be used.  I had a dual boot using the Windows bootloader and I think that's all I did.

Comment: I already have windows 7 installed, sorry. Is there another way, and do you know the answer to the first question?